# tumblr custom script not loading on mobile

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I added a custom script right before the default Google Analytics script to my Tumblr which just uses the default theme. Everything works just fine when I load the page on a desktop. It also loads fine in the tumblr app on my iPhone. But it does not load in Safari on my iPhone. Using the inspector I can see that the script just doesn't exist in the DOM. Anybody know why this is happening?

If you'd like to see the site it is located at [shepherdhusky.tumblr.com](http://shepherdhusky.tumblr.com)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. If you got to "Edit Theme > Advanced Options" There is an option to "Use Default Mobile Theme" which is checked by default. Turning that off means my script will no longer be overridden. But what else do I lose by turning off the Mobile Theme? I don't know...looks the same.